# how to return index of element by protractor filter(function (elem, index){)}

Tags: protractor

```
 WSManager.ListedWSLabel.filter(function (elem, index) {
    return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
      if( text.toUpperCase() === WSName.toUpperCase()){
        return index;
      };
    });
  }).then(function (returnedindex) {
    console.log("==============returnedindex==================",returnedindex);
    WSManager.AllListedWS.get(returnedindex).all(by.repeater("instance in tab.instances"));
  });
```

I want to return index of the element if text is matching and use this index to find another element, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter()` is used to filter out the item is meet the condition. It return part/all items of the original array, or empty array if no item meets the condition.

So the item in `filter()`'s return value can only be the same type of the original array. That's why you can not get the index. You only can get web element.

There are several ways to resolve your issue.

```
WSManager.ListedWSLabel.getText().then((txts)=>{
    return txts.findIndex((it)=>{
        return it.toUpperCase() === WSName.toUpperCase()
    });
});

// using map()
WSManager.ListedWSLabel.getText().map((ele)=>{
    return ele.getText();
})
.then((txts)=>{
    return txts.findIndex((it)=>{
        return it.toUpperCase() === WSName.toUpperCase()
    });
});
```